# How to implement a custom Django login?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a custom login in Django instead of using Django inbuilt login system. I don't know whether it's possible or not. Is this possible? I want to capture the value form the login template form. I have tried many ways but it's not working.

**This is my backend code**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = ''
        return render(request, 'mytest/login.html', {'context': context})

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        context = ''
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        print(username)
        print(password)


        return render(request, 'mytest/login.html', {'context': context})
```

**This is my login template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="username" required><br>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `It's not working` doesn't tell much. Pls, make the question more specific

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting to happen. None of your code actually does anything to log the user in.

Comment: @LatikaAgarwal: regarding your edit, software and library names should not be rendered in code formatting. They are proper nouns, so an initial capital (e.g. Django) is just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible.
First You must authenticate user, then just call login function.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

In Your code it will look like this:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = ''
        return render(request, 'mytest/login.html', {'context': context})

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page?
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            context = {'error': 'Wrong credintials'}  # to display error?
            return render(request, 'mytest/login.html', {'context': context})
```

Two things:

- context can be ommited if is empty (render function really needs only
  two first parameters: request and template)
- do not print, debug code
  using debugger :)